# Generic OAuth Client for Microsoft Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015, dynamics-crm-2016

I have created an integration with Microsoft Dynamics CRM using their REST API. For this I registered my OAuth Client app in Azure AD. This gave me the client id and client secret to perform OAuth.

I created the OAuth client app in my tenant(ISV's tenant). Can I use this client with other tenants?

In the login URL, I tried to replace my tenant id with target tenant id and got this error on login screen -

```
Application with identifier 'a67a2a59-9bf8-417c-a59e-809fea872b9d' was not found in the directory c7d9eacc-ff4c-499b-8f7f-de7a2daf9af2
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to set application as Multi Tenant in Azure AD.

I also figured out that in OAuth URLs I don't need to provide Tenant Id but can instead use `common`

I found this thread very helpful in figuring the solution - https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/212493